# Using libertine Sans Serif font along with LaTeX typewriter default font

Tags: fonts

How can I use the default `LaTeX` typewriter font along with a Sans Serif `libertine` font?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,headheight=5\baselineskip,headsep=1\baselineskip,includehead]{geometry}


\usepackage[scaled]{libertine} 
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{sectsty} 
\sectionfont{\sc\sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{0.5pt}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{test1}
\chead{test2}
\rhead{\texttt{xy@z.com}}

\begin{document}
\section*{My Section Heading}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

The typewriter font in the output PDF does not match with the rest of the document and actually looks weird, as shown in the following picture (a magnified version of the picture is also illustrated).

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to add the option `mono=false` (or `tt=false`) to

```
\usepackage[scaled, mono=false]{libertine}
```

This is described at the `libertine` [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/libertine/doc/libertine.pdf):

> Use the `mono=false` (or `tt=false`) option to suppress
>   activating LibertineMono.